# Number of binary coincidences on fix length binary numbers on python

Tags: python, binary, bin

So what I need is a python function to count the binary that are coincident on two numbers written in binary but with a fixed, known length. For example, if `n = 8` is the binary length, then:

```
a = 0011 0110
b = 0101 1111
--------------
c = 1001 0110 -> 4
```

Should get a result of `4`. each `0` on c is a non coincidence and each `1` means coincidence. As c has 4 one's, then the result is 4.

I need it to be **as fast as possible**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was my final solution that I think is quite effective:

```
bin(a ^ b)[2:].zfill(n).count("0")
```

**Explanation**
The logic was to use xor to get the number of coincidences. With XOR, I actually get the inverse of the example done in the question, as a coincidence will mean a `0` and a non coincidence will mean a `1`. So I will have to negate it, but before that I should make the number of `n` size because the answer is actually `110 1001` and so I'll get a response of 3 instead of 4.